# Integrar info propia de producto a boton de pago

Tags: php, html, mercadopago

Necesito saber cómo integro un id de producto al botón de pago y como me lo informa luego Mercado pago.

Adjunto imagen para explicar mejor. Tengo listados de cupones,
todos deben llevar su id para luego poder identificarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, por lo que entiendo necesitas asignar un tipo de "id" a los botones o cupones que estás listando.

Lo que tienes que hacer es una de dos, generar el id de tu objeto desde tu backend y concatenarlo en el atributo "id" de tu HTML:

```
<?php

$pagos_ids = array('17625', '2882', '66244');

foreach( $pagos_ids as $pago_id ){
   echo '<a href="mi-enlace" id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-' . $pago_id . '">Pagar</a>';
}
```

El resultado renderizado

```
<a href="un-enlace" id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-17625">Pagar</a>
<a href="un-enlace" id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-2882">Pagar</a>
<a href="un-enlace" id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-66244">Pagar</a>
```

Si no estás a gusto con usar el atributo "id", puedes usar el atributo "data":

```
<a href="un-enlace" data-pago-id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-17625">Pagar</a>
<a href="un-enlace" data-pago-id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-2882">Pagar</a>
<a href="un-enlace" data-pago-id="mi-boton-de-pago-generado--pagar-id-66244">Pagar</a>
```

Recuerdas, esos ids los generas desde tu PHP, y ya que estén generados, después puedes manipular esos ids con JavaScript.

Espero haber respondido tu respuesta. Saludos.